# Akka HTTP Actor System

Tags: scala, akka-http

I basically wanted to understand actor model in proper manner.
I want to understand what is akka actor, actorsystem, actormaterializer, actorreffactory and dispatcher in the below code.

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.http.scaladsl.Http
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives._
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer

import scala.io.StdIn

object MainRunner extends App {

  implicit val system = ActorSystem("mySystem")
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer
  implicit val ec = system.dispatcher

  val route =
    path("hello") {
      get {
        complete("Congratulation , this is your response")
      }
    }

  val bindingFuture = Http().bindAndHandle(route, "localhost", 8080)

  println(s"Server online at http://localhost:8080/\nPress RETURN to stop...")
  StdIn.readLine() // let it run until user presses return
  bindingFuture
    .flatMap(_.unbind()) // trigger unbinding from the port
    .onComplete(_ => system.terminate()) // and shutdown when done
}
```

Comment: There's a lot going on even in this tiny code snippet. If you want us to explain the whole thing to you that would require at least a few pages of documentation. You should read up on this stuff yourself and come back when you have a specific point of confusion.

Comment: Can you suggest something other than the documentation

Answer (score 1):

If you want to *really* understand Actor model, the wikipedia [entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model) is your best bet. If you want to understand Actors in Akka, Akka [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/general/actors.html) on it is your best bet(ActorSystem, Dispatcher are implementation detail of Akka Actor model implementation). Only after you understand that should you move to Akka-HTTP. Its based on the concept of Streams, which can be loosely defined as Lazy lists. Akka streams are "materialized" through ActorMaterializer. Happy Learning!

Answer (score 0):

Is it a valid StackOverflow answer to tell people to get a book? Well, if it is, I might just have the right tip for you - you can get the first 3 chapters of [Akka in Action](https://www.manning.com/books/akka-in-action) for free from the [Lightbend Website](https://info.lightbend.com/EBK-20XX-Akka-in-Action_LP.html) (free registration required). If I recall correctly, chapter 2 has a code snippet much like yours and explains it line by line.